# Passing by reference through multiple methods in C - value lost

Tags: c, reference, pass-by-reference

I have multiple nested methods that pass a variable by reference, but the reference seems lost somewhere in the stack and instead it creates a copy of the value so the value is not updated.

Here is my C code:

**method_1.c,method_2.c,method_3.c,method_4.c:**

```
uint8_t *signal_in_methods = 0;

void method_1(void *param){
  uint8_t *sig = (uint8_t*)param;
  method_2(sig);
}

void method_2(uint8_t *sig){
  method_3(sig);
}

void method_3(uint8_t *sig){
  method_4(sig);
}

void method_4(uint8_t *sig){
  signal_in_methods = *sig;
  //uses the signal_in_methods in separate thread, but this value is not updated when updated in main function
  ...
  while(1) {
    sleep(1000);
    uint8_t signal = *signal_in_methods;
    printf("%d",signal);
  }
}
```

**main.c:**

```
uint8_t signal = 0;

main() {
  method_1(&signal);

  while(1) {
    signal = update_signal()//this method continuously changes the value 'signal'
  }
}
```

How can I pass the reference through these multiple methods correctly, so that when the variable is changed in the main function, the change will be seen by all the methods?

Comment: `uint8_t *sig = *(uint8_t*)param;` shouldn't compile (or at least give warnings) - you are assigning a `uint8_t` to a `uint8_t*`

Comment: `uint8_t signal_in_methods` is a value - it can't "know" that some other value changed

Comment: After your latest code changes the line `signal_in_methods = *sig;` should give warnings

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I updated my code accordingly (see above), still the value won't change in method_4. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: before you do anything else, configure your compiler so that you see error messages for these mistakes (such as `signal_in_methods = *sig;`).

Comment: @UnholySheep Ah that was missing, now it works as expected.

Comment: regarding: `main() {`   Old C standards will default the returned type to `int`, however, you should not depend on `default` types.  Strongly suggest using: `int main( void )`

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  Amongst other things, it is missing the statement: `#include <stdint.h>` for the definition of `uint8_t`, etc

Comment: The posted code is missing the prototypes for the sub functions.

Comment: the posted code is missing the function: `update_signal()`

Comment: regarding: `  while(1) 
  {
    signal = update_signal()//this method continuously changes the value 'signal'
  }`  this code block will only be executed after all the other functions have been executed, Therefore, it serves no purpose.  Suggest removing that code block

Comment: regarding: `signal_in_methods = *sig;`  This is taking the value pointed to by `sig` (which is an integer value) and assigning that `int` value to a pointer.  The compiler outputs: "...:14:21: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]" which is an error

Comment: regarding: `//uses the signal_in_methods in separate thread, but this value is not updated when updated in main function`  However, the posted code contains only the 'main' thread

Comment: regarding: *still the value won't change in method_4. Any ideas how to solve this?*  Do you know about `pthread.h`? Do you know about the functions: `pthread_create()`, pthread_exit()`, etc?   Are you familiar with the concept of `race conditions`?  Do you know about the `pthread_mutex_t`, and `pthread_mutex_lock()` and `pthread_mutex_unlock()`?

Comment: regarding: `while(1) {
    signal = update_signal()//this method continuously changes the value 'signal'
  }` in function: `main()`:   This code will never be executed because the function: `method4()` never returns

Comment: regarding: `printf("%d",signal);` in `method4()`:  Outputting to `stdout` is buffered. So data will only display on the terminal when: 1) the stdout buffer overflows or 2) the program exits.  In general, always end the format string with `\n`, which forces an immediate flushing of the `stdout` buffer to the terminal

Comment: regarding: `void method_1(void *param){`   Why is the parameter declared as having type `void*` rather than: `uint8_t*`?